# Escape characters changing content of strings in python

Tags: python, path, escaping

I have this file path saved to a variable like so

```
path = "\\10.24.161.21\TVC-NL-Internal2\CPL\90_DAY\01_RUSHES\20210923\210923_90DF_FX9_LR_A001\XDROOT\Clip\A0002.MXF"
```

when I print I get this

```
'\\10.24.161.21\\TVC-NL-Internal2\\CPL\\90_DAY\x01_RUSHES\x8210923\x88923_90DF_FX9_LR_A001\\XDROOT\\Clip\\A0002.MXF'
```

the beginnings of some folder names are being altered by the backslash.

How do I avoid this?

Edit:
Thanks. I can hard code as raw strings. But I'm parsing a lot of strings from a text file and storing them in a list. How do I turn all of those into raw strings?

Comment: `path = r".....`.  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals.

Answer (score 0):

Use the raw string r to ignore the escape sequence in python
For example
Print(r"c:\10.24.56\users")

Comment: Thanks. This works if I hardcode it. But I'm parsing a lot of strings from a text file and storing them in a list. How do I turn all of those into raw strings?